# how to switch driver control from the top window to iframe#mainFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selenium, iframe

I am using firebug to inspect the xpath, one block of firebug shows the element your finding is in window or iframe and so on. I am facing similar kind of problem where it shows me 2 options 
1: Top window
2: iframe#mainframe
now the problem is,when i inspect the element it shows in iframe#mainFrame, i tried switching the driver control from main window to iframe and detect the element using webdriver but it didn't work for me,I wrote the following set of code:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("mainFrame");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='div_img']/img[@src='http://ser/themes/20/3/Flor/CF.jpg']")).click();
```

Note: when i checked the iframe in the html code,it doesn't contain another document inside it, It only contains id and other style and all and src tag.
Kindly suggest if there is some other way through which i can detect the element.

Comment: could you share the page / some html ?

Comment: Please share html markup for iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to switch to iframe like using frame id, name, index and through webElement.

Might be in your case, there might be no iframe id or name. Best way is to create an xpath that uniquely identifies the iframe, create a webelement using this xpath and pass this webelement to switch frame. This is more reliable.

Suppose you have markup like below:-

```
<div id='noticeRichText'>
<iframe height="83px" frameborder="0" width="100%" scrolling="NO" '1331808552380'"="" +="" src="initialize.do?init=header&cacheBuster="  marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"> 
</div>
```

Create a WebElement for iframe:-

```
WebElement iframe=
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='noticeRichText']/iframe"));
```

Switch to frame using above webelement:-

```
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
```

Perform the required actions on frame and then switch back to parent window using:-

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: i tried using what u just said, its not working out for me,i wrote the following code               {WebElement iframe=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td/iframe[@id='mainFrame']/iframe"));driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);}

Comment: I think you have captured xpath wrongly, i think it should be something like this:-                                                                 WebElement iframe=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td/iframe[@id='mainFrame']"));           If you can paste html markup, i could be able to suggest you correct xpath.

Comment: Thank you i am successfully able to switch to the frame and perform operation.

Answer (score -1):

for the window handling you can use this...

```
String baseWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
driver.switchTo().window(baseWindow);
```